# Using Adam's Law (Law of Total Expectation) to find expectation of residual

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

This may seem like a rather simple question, but I haven't been able to come up with an explanation myself or find one on the Internet.

I've learned that Adam's Law states that

$$E(E(Y|X)) = E(Y)$$

While solving an exercise problem, I noticed that the solution used the fact that

$$E(E(Y|X)|X) = E(Y|X)$$

I'm a bit confused as to how this equality has been derived. The form of Adam's Law with extra conditioning I'm familiar with is

$$E(E(Y|X, Z)|Z) = E(Y|Z)$$

but there seems to be something missing in the equation that I've given.

Would anybody be able to help me understand the derivation?

Thank you.

**EDIT**

The textbook that I'm using is *Introduction to Probability (1e) - Blitzstein & Hwang*.

There isn't particularly a specific definition regarding the property that I mentioned. If I were to quote the textbook exactly:

> Conditional expectation has some very useful properties, that often allow us to solve problems without having to go all the way back to the definition.
>
> ...
>
> Theorem 9.3.7 (Adam's Law): For any random variables $X$ and $Y$,
>
> $$E(E(Y|X)) = E(Y)$$
>
> Adam's law with extra conditioning:
>
> $$E(E(Y|X, Z) = E(Y|Z)$$

The remainder of the textbook related to the law is about how to prove the equality, which I understand how to do.

Here's the **specific exercise problem** that has led me to ask this question:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables with finite variances, and let $W = Y - E(Y|X)$.
>
> Compute $E(W|X)$.

**My approach** is as follows:

\begin{align}
E(W|X) & = E(Y - E(Y|X) | X) \\
& = E(Y|X) - E(E(Y|X)|X) \\
\end{align}

and this is the particular part that threw me off. The correct answer would be that $E(E(Y|X)|X) = E(Y|X)$ therefore giving us $0$.

Comment: $E(Y\mid X)$ is by definition measurable with respect to $\sigma(X)$, so it can be directly taken out of $E(\cdot \mid X)$.

Comment: Hi. I'm not too familiar with $\sigma (X)$... Could you post an explanation answer please?

Comment: It's well known that for a random variable $X:(\Omega, \Sigma) \to (E, \cal{E})$, $\sigma(X) = \{X^{-1}(B) \mid B \in \cal{E}\}$.

Comment: @Seankala You seem to be mainly in need of a **definition** of $E(Y\mid X)$. Do you know one?

Comment: Which definition of the conditional expectation $E(Y\mid X)$ do you know? If you give the context of your exercise (what book, which chapter are you reading?), it would be easy to tell.

Comment: Apologies everyone. I'll edit in some more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need it to read your book (the one by Blitzstein-Hwang you mentioned in the post) more thoroughly, really.

The definition you need is that of conditional expectations given a random variable. The first thing you should know is what the notation $E(Y|X)$ means before discussing anything about it. ***Section 9.2: Conditional expectation given an r.v.*** is the place you should refer to in the first place.

> [image]

Note that the whole **Section 9.3** is about "Properties of conditional expectation". In particular, you have

> [image]

Applying Theorem 9.3.2, one has
$$
E(E(Y|X)|X)=E(g(X)\cdot 1|X)=g(X)E(1|X)=g(X)\cdot 1=g(X),
$$
where $g(X):=E(Y|X)$.

---

[Added:] Note that a rigorous measure theory based answer to your question would be very different. (Even Definition 9.2.1 and statement of Theorem 9.3.2 would change in that setting.)

Answer (score 1):

As commenters point out, a definition would clear things up. Rick Durrett's *Probability* (free online) presents $E(X|\mathcal F)$ as the random variable $Z$ so that

1) $Z\in\mathcal F$, and

2) $\int_A XdP=\int_AZdP$ for all $A\in\mathcal F$.

To prove your fact, we have to show that

1) $E(E(Y|X)|X)\in \sigma(X)$, and

2) $\int_AE(E(Y|X)|X)dP=\int_AYdP$.

The first part follows from the fact that $E(E(Y|X)|X)$ is a random variable that results from conditioning on $\sigma(X)$. ($E(Y|X)$ means exactly $E(Y|\sigma(X))$.)

The second part follows from repeatedly applying property 2) for conditional expected values: For all $A\in\sigma(X)$,

$$\int_AE(E(Y|X)|X)dP=\int_AE(Y|X)dP=\int_AYdP,$$
with first equality by applying property 2) to the random variable that results from taking the expectation of $E(Y|X)$, conditioning on $\sigma(X)$; the second equality follows from applying property 2) to the random variable that results from taking the expectation of $Y$, conditioning on $\sigma(X)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use Rick Durrett's definition of conditional expectation to prove this result. Given a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_0,P)$, and a $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F} \subset \mathcal{F}_0$, and a random variable $X \in \mathcal{F}_0$ with $E[|X|]<\infty$, we define the conditional expectation of of $X$ given $\mathcal{F}$, $E[X|\mathcal{F}]$, to be a random variable $Y$ that has the following properties

1. $Y$ is $\mathcal{F}$-measurable.
2. for all $A \in \mathcal{F}, \, \int_A Y \, dP=\int_A X \, dP$.

We also know that conditional expectation exists and is unique (*Chapter 5.1 - Durrett - Probability Theory and Examples - 4th Edition*), so if $Y$ and $Y'$ satisfy conditions 1. and 2. then $Y\overset{a.s.}{=}Y'$.

Now on to the matter of the law of total expectation.

First note that since $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $\Omega \in \mathcal{F}$. Next, since $E[X|\mathcal{F}]$ is a random variable such that for all $ A \in \mathcal{F}, \, \int_A E[X|\mathcal{F}] \, dP = \int_A X \, dP$, this must also be true for $A=\Omega$.

Therefore we get

$$E[E[X|\mathcal{F}]] = \int_\Omega E[X|\mathcal{F}] \, dP = \int_\Omega X \, dP = E[X].$$